# Running OpenCL code on 14.04 with an NVIDIA GPU

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, opencl

I would like to use OpenCL with my Ubuntu desktop, with an NVIDIA Quadro K600 GPU. It is running the latest version of ubuntu (14.04.3 LTS).

I cannot successfully run an OpenCL Hello World example using this GPU, but I have. In the past, this was possible using the CUDA toolkit 6.5, which provided an openCL library and headers in `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/`

What are the steps to obtain a working OpenCL installation for this system? Various attempts I have made have resulted in an OpenCL library, but none so far seem to actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has become simpler since the last time I attempted this. The latest Nvidia drivers can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

will install various Nvidia tools in (at the time of this writing) `/usr/local/cuda-7.0`. This includes the library and include path needed to use OpenCL. On my machine these are

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/
```

The include path contains `CL/cl.h`

Comment: I don't have `nvidia-latest` package?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `nvidia-current`, I think (editing).